# Atribuições e permissões com NuxtJS e Vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js

**Pergunta**

— Existe alguma abordagem mais indicada / adequada para lidar com a liberação de acesso a conteúdo de páginas dependendo do perfil de um usuário logado utilizando Vuex e Nuxt?

**O que eu quero fazer**

Ao logar no admin, dependendo do perfil do usuário logado (Exemplo: Usuário, Produtor, Comprador, Entregador), é apresentada uma lista com links no componente sidebar — o usuário poderá ter múltiplos perfis (Exemplo: pode ser Produtor e Entregador, etc)

**Como estou pensando em fazer no momento**

Pensei em salvar o(s) perfil(s) do usuário logado em um array no state e depois utilizar esta informação no componente. Neste caso eu teria a lista com todos os links no component e faria um v-if para apresentar o conteúdo de acordo com o perfil.

E além disso teria alguns middlewares para controlar o acesso as páginas.

```
export const state = () => ({
  perfilDoUsuario: [ 'Usuario', 'Produtor' ] // ou por exemplo [ 'Usuário', 'Produtor', 'Comprador' ]
```

Comment: Talvez o [vue-kindergarten](https://github.com/JiriChara/vue-kindergarten) seja uma boa alternativa.

Comment: dei uma olhada, mas não sei como faria para adapta-lo a minha necessidade. pretendo liberar o acesso a determinadas partes da ferramenta com base em um conteúdo que pode existir em determinados campos do objeto do usuário — exemplo: eu pegaria esta informação na autenticação do usuário — produtosDoUsuario: [ idProduto1, idProduto2 ] — existindo produtos na array, eu liberaria o conteúdo de produtor para o usuário. pensei em fazer da seguinte forma: setar algo como usuarioTemProdutos como true (mutation) e depois fazer um getter tipo usuarioProdutor para usar nos componentes e página.